# How to check content of a volume from Dockerfile or compose file?

Tags: docker

I would like to have a docker volume to persist data. The persisted data can be accessed by different containers based on different images.

It is not a host volume. It is a volume listed in **volumes** panel of Docker Desktop.
[image]

For example, the name of the volume is `theVolume` which is mounted at `/workspace`. The directory I need to inspect is `/workspace/project`.

I need to check whether a specific directory is available inside the volume. If it is not, create the directory, else leave it as is.

Is it possible to do this from within a Dockerfile or compose file?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this in an entrypoint wrapper script.  This runs as the main container process, so it's invoked after the volume is mounted in the container.  The script isn't aware of what specific thing might be mounted on `/workspace`, so this will work whether you've mounted a named volume, a host directory, or nothing at all.  It does need to make sure to actually start the main container command when it's done.

```bash
#!/bin/sh
# entrypoint.sh

# Create the project directory if it doesn't exist
if [ ! -d /workspace/project ]; then
  mkdir /workspace/project
fi

# Run the main container command
exec "$@"
```

Make sure this file is executable on your host system (run `chmod +x entrypoint.sh` before checking it in).  Make sure it's included in your Docker image, and then make this script be the image's `ENTRYPOINT`.

```bash
COPY entrypoint.sh ./           # if a previous `COPY ./ ./` doesn't already get it
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]  # must use JSON-array syntax
CMD the main container command  # same as you have now
```

(If you're using `ENTRYPOINT` for the main container command, you may need to change it to `CMD` for this to work; if you've split the interpreter into its own `ENTRYPOINT` line, combine the whole container command into a single `CMD`.)

A Dockerfile `RUN` command happens before the volume is mounted (or maybe even exists at all) and so it can't modify the volume contents.  A Compose file doesn't have any way to run commands, beyond replacing the image's entrypoint and command.